# Get boolean value from JDBC

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

So I was using jdbc and trying to get a Boolean return value from the execute(sql) method after updating my db table. Following is the code:

```
try{
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = "update emp_earnings set salary = 6400 where lower(name)= 'bob'";
    Boolean result = stmt.execute(sql);
    System.out.println("rows affected (Y/N): " + result );
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("some error in second");
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```

When I check in my db table, the salary is updated but the `execute(sql)` has returned a 'false'.
I get an output as 'false' despite `execute()` working doing its job.
I checked the net , it says that it should return 'true' if worked. The `executeUpdate()` returns the 'no of rows affected' fine when i use that in the same code instead of `execute()` and is giving the required output.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The best place to find the answer to this type of question are the [JDBC Database Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) tutorials and the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-)

Comment: *"what am i doing wrong?"* You're not reading the documentation of [`execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-), because it says: ***Returns** true if the first result is a ResultSet object; **false if it is an update count** or there are no results*. --- If you want the update count, you should call [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-): *Returns [...] the row count*.

Comment: What does this have to do with [PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info) or [PL/SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsqldeveloper/info)?

Comment: @William Robertson i thought it cud have been a db error as well . becoz i m running a trigger on the table too. i thought something might be constraining it.

Comment: There's no [PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info) in the example and [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html) doesn't use JDBC. I've updated the tags to Oracle and SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String%29):

> boolean execute(String sql) throws SQLException
>
> Returns:
>
> true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if it is an
>   update count or there are no results

Here you are running an update command inside execute method, which will return update count. So it will return false for that update count.

Comment: Thanks Sachin .That answers it !

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want to do `int result = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);` which will return the count of affected rows, this is to say 0 if the update did not changed any row.